# Include class type on objects in writeJSON (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialise `POJO` into `JSON` with class type `@type` included.

Example of the `JSON` I'm trying to achieve:

```
{
   "@type":"com.train.model.AvailabilityResponsePojo",
   "code":"00",
   "message":"SUCCESS",
   "payload":[
      {
         "arrivaldate":"2019-03-01",
         "arrivaltime":"0800",
         "@type":"com.train.model.Train",
         "departdate":"2019-03-01",
         "fares":[
            {
               "amount":"110000",
               "@type":"com.train.model.Fares",
               "id":"123456",
               "pessengertype":null
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I've read about this annotation

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "@type")
```

But I can't somehow make it appear in the `JSON`. Do I need to add that line of code onto the class that does the conversion? Or the `POJO` class?
Any enlightment on this newbie coder would be appreciated.'

Edit:
This is my current Pojo:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "code",
    "message",
    "payload"
})
public class Train {

    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, include=JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "@type")
    @JsonProperty("code")
    private String code;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("payload")
    private List<Payload> payload = null;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
//Getter
//Setter
```

Comment: @Anfell, What do you mean by "I am trying to convert Json string into Json file"? You are trying to serialise `Java` object to `JSON` if I see correctly. Could you please clarify your description?

Comment: @MichałZiober Sorry for not explaining well on the question, yes the main idea was to serialize Java object to JSON but my initial data was a Json string `"{\"code\": \"00\", \"message\": \"SUCCESS\",\"payload\": [{\"arrivaldate\": \"2019-03-01\",\"arrivaltime\": \"0800\",\"bookingcode\": null, \"departdate\": \"2019-03-01\",\"departtime\": null, \"fares\": [{ \"amount\": \"110000\", \"id\": \"3827090\", \"pessagertype\": null }]}]}"` which didn't have class types yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `JsonTypeInfo` annotation on class level:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "code",
    "message",
    "payload"
})
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "@type")
class Train {
```

`include` is set to `JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY` by default, so, you do not need to specify it.

See also:

1. [Inheritance with Jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance)
2. [More Jackson Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-advanced-annotations)